# Nodejs memory leak, heapdump shows retainer showing "uncaught exception"

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, v8

My node application is very slowly leaking memory. I've carefully profiled everything generating heapdumps every minutes and comparing object allocations.

Everything seems to be fine except in (array) I have a whole load ( and ever increasing number ) of 24 bytes. With the retainer showing the array in "uncaughtException". See screen shot here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/18uRI.png

For the life of me I can't figure out what this means any help or walkthrough of the above would be *amazingly* appreciated.

Thank you

Edit:

To clarify the application crashes after around an hour with enomem exception. Running node 0.12.7

Edit 2:

The reason for the retainer showing uncaughtException was due to that event being attached to in the class. I've not been able to get rid of the memory leak, I suspect it's somewhere within node, however I've been able to mitigate it by destroying and rebuilding the stream periodically.

Comment: That screen shot only shows 240 items in that array.  How have you concluded that you for sure have a leak?  There are all sorts of caches and other data structures that consume memory in the interest of optimizing performance, but are not actually leaks.  If you let things run long enough they settle into a steady state.  So, what you have done to be sure you actually have a leak and not just some working memory that grows to a certain size as the system is used.

Comment: After an hour or so the application crashes with enomem. The screen shot above was just after first run. Everything else looks good other than these blasted small arrays building up.

Comment: Please add that information about a crash when running out of memory to your question as that is very material.  I think it's going to be very hard for us to diagnose this with out knowing your code and without the ability to poke around in the heap snapshot to try to figure out what is really there.

Comment: I worried that might be the case. What's weird is that buffer is in a private object inside a class that inherits from stream so it's not even *my* code persay. Added comment about crash. Thank you :)

Comment: I saw the references to streams.  I wondered if you might be leaking streams or some object that contains a stream, but not knowing anything about your code I had no idea if that was relevant.

Comment: Impossible to tell without code.  But the majority of memory leaks I've encountered in node were due to async writes getting backed up, which can easily be fixed by having writes run synchronously.  Just something to consider, but once again impossible to tell based off there not being any code to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I was using this library (https://github.com/maxogden/multiplex) which was leaking empty arrays https://github.com/maxogden/multiplex/issues/31.